# Flutter: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Document>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the error "type 'Future dynamic' is not a subtype of type 'Future Document'" and can't figure out where this 'Future dynamic' comes from.

Here I'm trying to construct a document edit page in Flutter, loading the document from API by id and using FutureBuilder to actually show the page when the document is loaded:

```
...

class _UpdateNotePageState extends State<UpdateNotePage> {
  final String id;
  DocumentBloc _bloc;
  Future<Document> document;

  _UpdateNotePageState({this.id}) {
    _bloc = DocumentBloc();
    document = _bloc.getDocument(id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: document,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Document> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(id),
                      NoteForm(document: snapshot.data),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return new CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the getDocument() code (returning Future Document):

```
...
class DocumentRepository {
...
  Future<Document> getDocument(String id) async {
    final response = await _api.get("documents/$id");
    return Document.fromJson(response);
  }
...
}

class DocumentBloc {
...
  getDocument(String id) async {
    return await _documentRepository.getDocument(id);
  }
...
}
```

And here's Document.fromJson() just in case:

```
class Document {
...
  Document.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
  }
...
}
```

`_api.get()` returns `json.decode(response.body.toString())`

Why 'Future dynamic'? What did I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, it's just a mess of sync/async calls on different abstraction levels, poor understanding of Future etc. Long story short, I've needed to change this

```
getDocument(String id) async {
  return await _documentRepository.getDocument(id);
}
```

to this

```
Future<Document> getDocument(String id) async {
  return _documentRepository.getDocument(id);
}
```

and then pass this `_bloc.getDocument(id)` to the `FutureBuilder` as is.

Answer (score 0):

In your class DocumentRepository, inside getDocument function, make the following changes (json.decode(response.body)):-

```
class DocumentRepository {
...
  Future<Document> getDocument(String id) async {
    final response = await _api.get("documents/$id");
    return Document.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Not relevant. response is already decoded. I'll amend the question now